# Play2 Implicit Writes<T> in Java

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have some problem calling my Scala code from Java.

Here is my Scala Class:

```
case class Foobar(foo: String) extends FoobarParent

object Foobar {

    implicit object Format extends Format[Foobar] {
        def writes(Foobar: foobar): JsValue = {       
           ....
        }

        implicit def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Foobar] = {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I have a method with the following signature:

```
def publish[T <: FoobarParent](foobarParent: T)(implicit writes: Writes[T]): Unit = {...}
```

This works fine when calling from Scala code, I simply just do `publish[Foobar] (Foobar(...))`

However in Java, the signature looks likes this in my IDE:

```
publish (T FoobarParent, Writes<T> writes)
```

Now my question is what/how do I fulfil those two parameters in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually can get an object's instance like this: `Foobar$.MODULE$`
and the nested one like this: `Foobar.Format$.MODULE$`

There's a problem with the companion object here though, because it gets compiled as a different class. It will create a class named `Foobar$` which is not of the type `Foobar` nor does it extends `FoobarParent`. So you can't just call `publish(Foobar$.MODULE$, Foobar.Format$.MODULE$);`. I think you'll just have to create a new instance:

```
publish(new Foobar("..."), Foobar.Format$.MODULE$);
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like my IDE is satisfied with Foobar.Format$.MODULE$